# Как передать данные из формы в dll?

Tags: c#, форма, dll

Приветствую всех!
Интересует такой вопрос: как передать данные из формы в dll?
Например через Drag'n'Drop получаю путь к файлу, а потом передать его в dll.

Comment: Сделайте вопрос более конкретным. Непонятно, в чем проблема, что вы делали для ее решения.

Comment: Бродил по интернету большое количество времени, но так ничего и не нашел. Суть такая. Я бросаю файл на форму через D'n'D получаю путь к этому файлу. Есть самописная dll, в ней реализовано открытие файла. Вопрос состоит в том, как передать этот путь из формы в dll для открытия файла.

Comment: представьте что передаете это имя в качестве параметра в функцию в своей программе. реализуйте. далее реализуйте решение с загрузкой длл и вызовом ее функции. или конкретно интересует сам способ работы с Drag'n'Drop?

Comment: Все, разобрался. Всем спасибо!